# Two elements in the same conjugacy class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The wikiproof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_Conjugates_is_Number_of_Cosets_of_Centralizer) claims that if $x,y\in C_a$ the conjugacy class of $a$, then 
$$xax^{-1} = yay^{-1}.$$
I do not quite see why this is true. For example, let $G = S_4$, and $a=(12)$, then $(13),(34) \in C_{(12)}$ but $$(13)(12)(13) \neq (34)(12)(34).$$

Comment: You are right, and there is a typo on the linked page. I guess they want to consider two conjugates of $a$ by $x$ and $y$, and then $x\,a\,x^{-1} = y\,a\,y^{-1}$ is equivalent to $x^{-1}\,y \in C_G (a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only correct statement in this respect is that $x^{-1}ax \in C_a \forall x \in G$. So in your example: $(1,3)(1,2)(1,3) = (2,3) \in C_{(1,2)}$ and $(3,4)(1,2)(3,4) = (1,2) \in C_{(1,2)}$.